# How to check if php has successfully run db queries using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Here, I have this jQuery code that passes values to a php file that handles database queries.

```
$("#item-input-form__complete-form-btn").click(function(){
var invoiceInfo = {
    "date"           : $("[name=datepicker]").val(),
    "op_id"          : 11111,
    "invoice_number" : $("[name=invoice]").val(),
    "vendor_id"      : 33333
};
var jsonResult = $('#added-items__table').tableToJSON();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert_items_to_db.php",
    data: {QUERY_TYPE:"INSERT",
           INVOICE_INFO:invoiceInfo,
           JSON_RESULT:jsonResult},
    success: function(){alert("SUCCEEDED");},
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
         var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      }
});
});
```

And here I have the php file that handles the passed parameters and run queries.

insert_items_to_db.php::

```
<?php
include_once('models/dbapi.php');
$query_type = $_REQUEST["QUERY_TYPE"];
$invoice_info = $_REQUEST["INVOICE_INFO"];
$product_json = $_REQUEST["JSON_RESULT"];

$DB = new DBAPI();
$DB->connectTo('BBY');
$DB->insertDataIntoStockMasterTable($invoice_info, $product_json);
$DB->insertDataIntoStockDetailTable($invoice_info, $product_json);
$DB->disconnect();
?>
```

And the method in DBAPI class that runs queries looks something like this.

dbapi.php ::

```
    function insertDataIntoStockMasterTable($invoice_info, $product_json)
    {
        $invoice_date   = $invoice_info['date'];
        $invoice_number = $invoice_info['invoice_number'];
        $op_id          = $invoice_info['op_id'];
        $vendor_id      = $invoice_info['vendor_id'];

        $today_date     = date("Y-m-d");
        $invoice_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($invoice_date)); 

        $total_amt = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($product_json); $i++)
        {
            $total_amt += $product_json[$i]['Extended Price'];
        }

        $query ="INSERT INTO stock_master (sm_date, sm_invoice_no, sm_vendor_cd, total_amt, op_id, op_date)
                        VALUES('$invoice_date', $invoice_number, $vendor_id, $total_amt, $op_id, '$today_date')";

        $result = mssql_query($query, $this->selected_hannam_db_server);
        return $result;
    }
```

The problem here is... I can't figure out how to check whether queries have crashed. In such cases, jquery should pop up a msg box telling users that inserting data into db has failed.

How can I pass error msgs from php to jquery?

Comment: You would have to have your php return something jquery can understand when there is an error.

Comment: How can I catch that using jQuery? I don't think error:  is doing that job.

Comment: You can't catch it using jQuery, the error happens on the server and jQuery is client-side.

Comment: @KevinB actually you *could* return a 5xx status from the server using PHP's `header();` function, which would trigger the error handler on jquery's `$.ajax()` function. Something like `header('Status:500');` (don't copypasta that, it's just pesudo). more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Yes, you could, but again, you would have to do that on the server, then handle it in jquery. jQuery can't do it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soemthing like this could work for you.

### PHP code

```
if( $DB->insertDataIntoStockDetailTable($invoice_info, $product_json) ) {
    $result['result'] = true;  
    $result['error'] = '';

} else {
    $result['result'] = false;  
    $result['error'] = 'Insert failed.';
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = json_encode($result);
echo $data;
```

### Java Script Code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert_items_to_db.php",
    data: {QUERY_TYPE:"INSERT",
           INVOICE_INFO:invoiceInfo,
           JSON_RESULT:jsonResult},
    success: successResponseHandler,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
         var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      }
});


function successResponseHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    if( data['result'] == true){
        // DO Something here
    } else {
       // Display the error message with text from data['error']
    }
}
```

Comment: You should replace true by 1 and false by 0 in your php. I am not sure that you can passe boolean between php->json->javascript

Comment: Thanks !! Works perfectly! Never knew about header b4 :)

Comment: @bleuscyther About the only things json doesn't support are recursion and dates (that is, there are multiple "standards" for date encoding and different libraries implement different standards which can be a pain). String/Boolean/Int/Double/etc... are all fine